# XNA LocalNetworkGamer.isDataAvailable

Tags: c#, xna, network-programming

I am a little bit confused by this. Is this data which is available to the local player from a remote player on another machine or is this data available from the local player?

Answer (score 0):

The *LocalNetworkGamer* class represents the local player in the multiplayer session. [MSDN LocalNetworkGamer Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.net.localnetworkgamer.aspx)

The **IsDataAvailable** property determines whether incoming data is available from a remote player.

See the documentation: [MSDN LocalNetworkGamer.IsDataAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.net.localnetworkgamer.isdataavailable.aspx)

Usually you would setup some sort of processing loop, and query this property for available incoming data from remote players.

Example availble on this page: http://geekswithblogs.net/JoshReuben/archive/2011/06/28/xna-multiplayer-games-and-networking.aspx